# I have a problem with SQL query for select count of ID

Tags: sql, count, phpmyadmin, inner-join

I have a problem with COUNT - INNER JOIN query, I tried to find a soluton, but I didn't..
Someone have idea what is the problem? Thanks on answer!

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS total
FROM products 
INNER JOIN `navigation_items` 
ON navigation_items.id = products.navigation_item 
INNER JOIN `navigation_items_group` 
ON navigation_items_group.id = products.navigation_item_group 
INNER JOIN `navigation_items_brand` 
ON navigation_items_brand.id = products.navigation_item_brand 
WHERE navigation_items.id='1' AND navigation_items_group.id='1' AND navigation_items_brand.id='1'
```

[This is image od my database table 'products'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1rrN.png)

[This is the error message what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhisV.png)

Comment: The Error output is telling you what's the problem: `#1052 - Column id is ambiguous`. Basically you need to tell him what's the table that `id` belongs to, as long as several tables you have joined have that column name.

Comment: Do u thing, something like products.id?

Comment: Can't give you an insightful answer a-priori without knowing your tables structure and what you want to achieve with your query.

Comment: Yes I try that and it works, thank you!